# shapefile and dataset aggregate into one by coordinates

Tags: r

I have a shapefile like this (ms_shp)

| Region | Residuals | Residuals 1 | Residuals2 | Residuals 3 | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 2017 | 1 | 1 | list(list(c(..) |
| 2 | 540 | 2017 | 2 | 2 | list(list(c(..) |

and   is geometry  type multipolygon and  has de dimension xy and is boundyîng box with xmin and  ymin .

I have another dataset like this (ses)

| gisid | gx | gy | mean_dist | bp2 | sep | sep_q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 248779981 | 111999 | 785.8 | 0 | 9 | 21 |
| 2 | 249887771 | 244399 | 766.6 | 1 | 21 | 39 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on something similar, the function exact_extract from the package exactextractr has worked very well in terms of processing time and ease of use. The following code will calculate the mean of variable z from every value within each polygon.

```
library(exactextractr)
library(raster)
library(terra)


#Read in the csv
ses_csv <- read.csv(ses)

#Cut it down to three columns where the first and second columns are x any y coords and the third is the z variable you want to investigate, use your method of choice for this.

#Create a raster that is compatible with exactextract from ses
ses_raster <- terra::rast(raster::rasterFromXYZ(ses_csv,crs='whatever the crs is for the data')

#Read in the shapefile
ms_shp <- terra::vect(ms_shp)

#Calculate the mean z values for each polygon
    exact_extract(ses,ms_shp,'mean')
```

Comment: I would like that  gisid that lie on the polygon, so geometry of the regions aggregate to that regions with the mean ssep1 of all gisid in the same regions

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that, it now contains an explanation of what you need to do and should work once you put your own variables in.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to summarize (aggregate) values associated with points by the polygons that they intersect with. And then add these as new variables to the polygons.
With "terra" version 1.6-1 (currently the development version, you can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')` you can use `zonal` for that.

Example data (please always include some)

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.6.1

# example polygons
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
polys <- vect(f)[,c(2,4)]

# example points 
set.seed(1)
pnts <- spatSample(polys, 100)
values(pnts) <- data.frame(b2=1:100, ssep1=100:1)
```

Solution

```
z <-  zonal(pnts, polys, mean, as.polygons=TRUE)
z
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 4  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :   NAME_1   NAME_2    b2 ssep1
# type        :    <chr>    <chr> <num> <num>
# values      : Diekirch Clervaux 51.14 49.86
#               Diekirch Diekirch    28    73
#               Diekirch  Redange 42.58 58.42
```